# Django data getting saved in wrong model Why its saving the Model B,C data in model A

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have 3 django models `CustomerDetail` `CarrierForm` `InfluencerModel` When i am trying to save data in `CarrierForm` or `InfluencerModel` through different different page's forms its getting saved in model `CustomerDetail` Why its happening tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here is Model

```html
class CustomerDetail(models.Model):
    full_name             = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    email                 = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    contact_number        = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    message               = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    visited_on            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class CarrierForm(models.Model):
    full_name             = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    email                 = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    contact_number        = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    upload_resume         = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
    message               = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    visited_on            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class InfluencerModel(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    instagram_id   = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    visited_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("influencers", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Rendering the forms like this

```
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" role="form" class="php-email-form" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
      {{ form.as_table }}
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          {{ form.full_name.errors }}
          {{form.full_name|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
             {{ form.email.errors }}
             {{form.email|as_crispy_field}}
<!--                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>-->
        </div>


      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ form.contact_number.errors }}
        {{form.contact_number|as_crispy_field}}
<!--                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>-->
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ form.instagram_id.errors }}
        {{form.instagram_id|as_crispy_field}}
<!--                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>-->
      </div>

          </div>



      <div class="form-group mt-3" rows="7">
        {{ form.message.errors }}
        {{form.message|as_crispy_field}}
<!--                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>-->
      </div>
<!--              <div class="my-3">-->
<!--                <div class="loading">Loading</div>-->
<!--                <div class="error-message"></div>-->
<!--                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>-->
<!--              </div>-->
       <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="background-color:#FF512F; color: white">Send Message</button>
     </div>
<!--              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>-->
    </form>
```

Urls

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('influencers/', InfluencersPageView.as_view(), name='influencers'),
    path('carrier/', CarrierFormView.as_view(), name='carrier'),
    
    ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure which template you're showing to us but simply try removing `action="{% url 'home' %}"`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i am showing the InfluencersPageView template. because of this 'action="{% url 'home' %}' its happening?

Comment: I'd assume `{% url 'home' %}` resolves to the URL for `HomeView` so yes that probably is the issue. You're basically submitting the form to the wrong page.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ya because of wrong redirect its happening..But if i am redirecting from my model using 'def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("influencers", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})' shows me ImproperlyConfigured at /influencers/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have only provided one template, I'd assume you're using the same form for all of those views you mentioned.
Your form action is pointing to the same url `home`. at `<form action="{% url 'home' %}" role="form" class="php-email-form" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}` . Change that accordingly to whichever view you'd want your form to be processed by.

Comment: Ya because of wrong redirect its happening..But if i am redirecting from my model using 'def get_absolute_url(self): return reverse("influencers", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})'  shows me ImproperlyConfigured at /influencers/ No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Comment: can you provide detail on that. update the question to include your models with the method and the urls file.

Comment: ya check it i added the url and def get_absolute_url(self): mrthod

Comment: You need to define a url with slug for a specific (single) influencer.  something like this:
`path('influencers/<slug:slug>/', InfluencerDetailView.as_view(), name='influencer_detail')`. And then in get_absolute_url method: `return reverse('influencer_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})`. also, your model doesn't include a slug field, look into that.

Comment: I don't want to return it to single influncer detail i just want that if the fill up the form after submitting the url redirect to same page. like before " <form action="{% url 'home' %}" " if i was redirected to home my data get saved some where else to avoid this i want to redirect to same "influncer"s page

Comment: then just do this : `return reverse("influencers")`